# variables from external file [SOLOVED]

Tags: php, variables

I would like to hear if this possible. Just any way I can get variables from an external file without include or require.

i-need-variables.php:

```
<?php
//what to do here (Not include or require)

echo $variable1;
echo $variable2;
echo $variable3;
?>
```

i-have-variables.php:

```
<?php
$variable1='hello';
$variable2='hey';
$variable3='hi';
//I also have some content "i-need-variables.php" dont need
?>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `require_once` or `include` ?

Comment: Without the context of *why* you want to do this, it's very hard for anyone to provide a good answer. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hard to explain? You need to explain, because this has no context and makes very little sense as it is.

Comment: @Digital Chris Its for a dynamic site. In the top of the i-have-variables.php file I would like having variables like $title, $keywords and $description (for seo). and then in the index.php echo them in the <head> section

Comment: At the top of index.php you would `include 'i-have-variables.php';`

Comment: @DigitalChris includes and requires are too mainstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An ugly fix .. This works..

I really don't have an idea why you are not using `require` or `include`..

```
<?php
//what to do here (Not include or require)
$var = file('test1.php');
array_shift($var);
array_filter($var);
$txt=implode('&',$var);
$txt=str_replace(array('$',';',"'",' '),'',$txt);
parse_str($txt);

echo $variable1;
echo $variable2;
echo $variable3;
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
hello hey hi
```

Comment: Thanks! @Shankar Damondaran

Comment: That's very ugly though :D

Comment: I hope you're ashamed of this one hehe

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Any way I can give you a medal or something on this site? (I voted for your answer and accepted it)

Comment: @DigitalChris Emmm why?

Comment: @KaareZ, That's enough :) Thanks. Yellow Bird and Chris.. This code will be really useful when `require` and `include` becomes extinct. :P

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I'm looking forward ! You will be some kind of PHP Avenger !

Answer (score 0):

There was a way of doing this using [register globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), but this is a deprecated feature as it was leading to bad code.

One solution is to store the variables in the session.